# is there any way to convert/import Microsoft Word documnet to Adobe InDesign book

Tags: conversion, indesign

Can we convert a Microsoft Word document to Adobe InDesign book?

When I tried to import Microsoft Mord document into Adobe InDesign, the software gave error as unsupported document.

If you know any workaround that will help a lot.

Comment: I think I should have done more searching as I got the solution at youtube. I found a link for "InDesign tutorial: How to import Microsoft Word files" which explains the process. I will still keep the question as a record for the where you can find the solution.

Comment: If you have found a way to do that, you can answer your own question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow these steps:

1. Create an `.indd` document
2. Set the page margins and document properties to mirror what you have on Microsoft word, or — better still — set these properties based on how you want your book to be.
3. Select File -> Place *or* `Ctrl+D`
4. From the dialog box, select the Microsoft Word file
5. Go through the Microsoft Word Import Options making sure you select what pertains to preserving the formatting of your work.
6. Import and apply character styles to your taste.